# Updated .cs file in another solution and cannot figure out how to reference updated version

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, dll

I have updated a .cs file in one solution that is being used by a .cs file in a second solution in VS 2010.  I have deleted the reference to the .dll file in the second solution and then re-referenced it but I'm still referencing the old dll.  Is there something else I have to do in order to get the correct version? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Make sure you rebuild the solution containing the file you modified.

Comment: Did you do a build on the solution that has the .cs file?

Comment: How is one referencing the other?  Any easy mistake to make it to add a reference to the release directory but rebuild in debug (or vice versa).

Comment: @SimpleCoder -That's what I didn't to do.  Thank you.

Comment: @AlexMendez No, I just saved it.  I rebuilt it and it works fine now.  Thank you.

Comment: @bmm6o I didn't build it at all, just saved it.  Once I built it everything worked fine.  Thank you.

Comment: Yeah, projects reference *assemblies*, not individual source files.  Your update isn't externally visible until it's in an assembly.

Comment: @bmm6o It made perfect sense once it was explained.  I should have thought of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to build the solution that contains the modified .cs. After building that solution, then you have to build the solution consuming the dll. If you still have problem with it, then it is possible that your project is not marked for compiling. If that is so, right click on the project itself (not the solution) and re-build the project.